# Circuit simulation of PWM has a rapid loss of voltage in Falstad

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, falstad

I made a PMW in falstad that works only for a few seconds bevor the voltage in whole circuit drops to zero. I already tried to redirect the diodes with no effect.

https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEDoE4DMAWATKhl0A2AdnVW0gA5lVll1kBTAWjDACgAlETat7KODADI4ZKJgQJUaAnYBjENgSEQhTEpXhC0mPEipDR4ydp7IU2BfYAzEOiJLK1dJQ3ZngsLJmRs7AHd7BAEwYlVMOHBwqECeKLAdeNEw1Uh2ABMePmEhAV4lEAzGGwBDAFcAGwAXTOjVfjzswuKyqtqsxtTmxoFWipq6rpju3qKSgdqgxoLlCOp06dzuufrYoNX1TXn17e1RVe70gBVkkEpRXhSPQQ0pQRgjONWCyMuFuLfmr4vYrKvzqIEORAS0Ju0FDQBL9gaEYhIrHBTMijL4LGiOEEAcJqNj4Z9ft1YWtFlC1sQKCS4sTfhTRL90gAnEB00Gso7geBxdAhNaHfHcHmhTAadCUsAiwT5eCaA74B7QDgAey8N0uBgWipUyjRcF4lA8wiQB0E6HYKuwoTV8UMaOwIolkEIOvMSPC2qQEAElvs7CAA

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why is there no ground reference? Why is one of the AC terminals of the diode bridge not connected to anything?

Comment: Added the ground, and changed voltage source from 100mV to 10V. [Here is the Link](http://tinyurl.com/2yhr2xzf).